# Git log showing password in author field

Tags: git, bitbucket

I can see the password of the git(Bitbucket) when I run `git log` command  locally.

```
commit af45fb439beb489f473b6e935dfc.....
Author: username <Password>
Date:   Sat Jun 10 15:32:30 2017 +0530
....
```

How I can remove password from author field from next check in as well as historical check ins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to rewrite the history of the branch setting up the right author. https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

Comment: thanks!  But do you know why my password is shown in logs so that next commit wont have it

Comment: I would guess that at some point you mistook the request to enter your username as a request for username and password, so you typed in both.

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen  I used  git config --list  to see the all the config .. and by mistake i put password in email field

Comment: That would certainly do it :) If you're the only author and user of this repository you should fix your username and email address, then use `git filter-branch` to rewrite history, google for the right way to do it. Also, and this is important, **do this on a clone** so that you can verify that everything looks 100% before you push. Lastly, a force push (`git push -f`) will overwrite your remote with your changes. **However**, if there are other people working in this repository, you need to talk to them before you do **anything**!

Comment: Why not just fix the .gitconfig and change the password (forget about rewrite the history)?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira i don't think leaving some passwords as part of the history is a great idea (even if the password is already modified). And if we were talking about something that has never happened, I'd understand to leave it as is... but git has the mechanism and plenty of articles talking about how to do it so I see no harm (or big hurdle) in rewriting the history.

Comment: It's up to you if you want to remove the password from history but: 1) you need to change your password anyway (because someone could have seen it already), 2) I can't see any issue in show a non valid password.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira We can agree to disagree :-)

Answer (score 2):

bro.

this problem is about your git config.

you can try to view you git config:

```
git config --list
```

so ,you can modify your gitconfig file to fix this problem.

```
vim ~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To reset your username in a commit:

```
git rebase -i <commit-id of the previous commit>
```

Once the editor opens, change the `pick` in front of the commit to be edited to `edit` . Save and exit.  Then,

```
git commit --amend --author="Author name <email>"

git rebase --continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. This link is quite helpful:[change author name](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email/)

If you want to change the author name only for the last commit, do `git commit --amend --author="name <email>"` and you should be good

Changing author info for multiple older commits can be done using git rebase. Refer to the above link for exact steps.

Also, edit the author name in your git config so that future commits will have the correct info.
vi ~/.gitconfig and edit the username field.